# Roblox Studio, how do I send a string through a remote event

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

This is the local script

```
button.Activated:Connect(function()
        remoteEvent:FireServer(button.Text.Text)
        game.Workspace.DimensionConfig.Value.Value = button.Text.Text
        
        
    end)
```

Here is the server script in Workspace.

```
local function changeValue(Name)
print("Did that")
print(Name)
game.Workspace.DimensionConfig.Value.Value = Name
end
remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(changeValue)
```

Then output

```
Did that  -  Server - Script:5
(my username)  -  Server - Script:6
  Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got Instance
```

I don't know why it prints my username.

Comment: I Get the error "attempt to call a string value"

Comment: Still it doesnt print the button.Text.Text When it prints name in prints my name.

Comment: Anyone who can help Please help i fixed the part with the attempted to call string value. but when I press the button the Server side variable in workspace still doesnt change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to have a player paramiter instead. Change your code to this

```
local function changeValue(player, Text)
print("Did that")
print(player)
print(Text)
-- Prints the player Name and text being sent.
game.Workspace.DimensionConfig.Value.Value = Text
end
remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(changeValue)
```

That should work. With remote events always make sure to add a "Player" parameter to the event function. When firing a remote event to be received server side. The Server always needs to know who sent it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is in `remoteEvent:FireServer(button.Text.Text())`. Assuming you have a TextLabel called "Text" inside button, you're trying to call that button's text (a string value) as a function.

Try changing that line to  `remoteEvent:FireServer(button.Text.Text)` instead.

Comment: Oh lol thanks that helped with that, but it when it prints it prints my Name and not the text I sent Through and i get the error  "Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got Instance" my goal is to when i press a cetain button it changes a string value in the workspace. It works client side but not Server side so im trying to use events to do that but I'm new to this so its proving difficult.

Comment: It sounds like `Text.Text` is a StringValue not a string. You could be sending `button.Text.Text.Value`

Comment: No, Text is the name of the label of the button So i want to send the text label ("Text") and the text property of the text label.